# Da dove proviene la frase "cambiare tutto per non cambiare niente" (scritta esattamente così)?

Tags: sentences, phrase-origin

Il titolo di [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5145/707) (adesso è cancellato, ma era "Cambiare tutto per non cambiare niente") ha attirato la mia attenzione. Leggendolo, mi sono subito domandata se questa frase fosse veramente un proverbio italiano o avesse qualcosa a che vedere col romanzo *Il Gattopardo* di Giuseppe Tomasi di Lampedusa. Una ricerca su Google conferma che molti siti web attribuiscono questa frase a Tomasi di Lampedusa. Ecco un [esempio](http://diario_di_borgo.ilcannocchiale.it/2013/04/28/percezionitutto_per_non_cambia.html):

> «"Bisogna cambiare tutto per non cambiare niente", così scriveva Giuseppe Tomasi di Lampedusa ne "Il Gattopardo". La formazione del nuovo governo ha realizzato pienamente ciò che ha scritto Tomasi di Lampedusa, ingannando per l'ennesima volta gli italiani onesti, quelli che sono sempre andati a votare onestamente, quelli che lavorano onestamente, rispettano le leggi e pagano le tasse onestamente.»

Tomasi di Lampedusa, però, non ha mai scritto questa frase ne *Il Gattopardo*. La frase che appare in questo romanzo, pronunciata da Tancredi, è:

> «Se vogliamo che tutto rimanga come è, bisogna che tutto cambi.»

Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è l'origine della frase "cambiare tutto per non cambiare niente"? Appare forse nella versione cinematografica di *Il Gattopardo*?

Comment: Mi pare quantomeno sorprendente che ci siano tanti siti web con una citazione letteraria sbagliata.

Comment: I understand the point you want to make, but I am afraid that it is just a modified version of the original sentence from The Gattopardo!

Comment: Ricerche su Google: "Cambiare tutto per non cambiare niente": 13700 risultati. "Se vogliamo che tutto rimanga come è, bisogna che tutto cambi": 8800 risultati. Dunque, la frase del titolo della domanda è molto più usata che quella che appare nel *Gattopardo*.

Comment: Ngram mostra questo trend, le due espressioni si riferiscono a quelle di cui stiamo parlando: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bisogna+che+tutto+cambi%2Cper+non+cambiare+niente&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbisogna%20che%20tutto%20cambi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cper%20non%20cambiare%20niente%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Anch'io la cito "sbagliata", così come cito in modo sbagliato "non ti curar di loro..." . Probabilmente è solamente perche la forma sbagliata e più vicina all'italiano moderno, e quindi più facile da ripetere e continuare a sentire da altri.

Answer (score 2):

No, la versione cinematografica riporta la citazione del libro. Ho trovato [questo spezzone su YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKZRNuGpXYM) ed è divertente constatare come l'abbiano sbagliata nel titolo nonostante tutto.

Ad ogni modo, penso che sia un caso simile a quello della Divina Commedia di Dante. Molti ad esempio dicono sempre "non ti curar di loro ma guarda e passa" (Inferno, canto III) al posto di "non ragioniam di lor, ma guarda e passa", che è il verso originale. Si tratta di storpiature diffuse nella cultura popolare. [Qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/non-ti-curar-di-lor-ma-guarda-e-passa/) un chiarimento della Treccani.

Comment: Sono grato a Giulia per aver rintracciato e segnalato la versione cinematografica, escludendo così che venga da lì la versione modificata, ma rimane aperto il problema di come sia nata quest'ultima. È vero, ci sono vare citazioni famose “sbagliate”, da Dante in poi, ma soprattutto in un caso come questo del Gattopardo, in cui non cambia una singola parola ma si ha una parafrasi completa, deve esserci qualcuno (scrittore? giornalista? politico?) che riformulò in questo modo il pensiero e fu a sua volta citato di frequente.

Comment: Ho provato a inserire la frase su Google Ngram, sperando di rintracciare la fonte, ma non ho trovato nessun risultato.

Comment: Al minuto 1:22 del [film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBPHLxSJ-xQ), Don Fabrizio, Principe di Salina, dice: "Qualcosa doveva cambiare perché tutto restasse com'era prima" (questa frase non appare nel romanzo), ma non è neanche questa la frase della domanda.

Comment: DaG ha ragione, ma non credo si possa far di meglio.

Answer (score 1):

Penso sia una frase coniata proprio ne [Il Gattopardo](http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_Gattopardo) in quanto incarna lo spirito siciliano che è uno dei temi principali dell'opera.

> - L'autore  compie all'interno dell'opera un processo narrativo che è sia storico che attuale. Parlando di eventi passati, Tomasi di Lampedusa parla di eventi del tempo presente, **ossia di uno spirito siciliano citato più volte come gattopardesco (" Se vogliamo che tutto rimanga come è, bisogna che tutto cambi")**.

- La frase è stata poi in seguito  formulata diversamente, senza comunque modificarne il significato.

[Gattopardismo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gattopardismo/): (Treccanionline)

> - s. m. (anche, meno comunem., gattopardite s. f.). – Nel linguaggio letter. e giornalistico, l’atteggiamento (tradizionalmente definito come trasformismo) proprio di chi, avendo fatto parte del ceto dominante o agiato in un precedente regime, si adatta a un nuova situazione politica, sociale o economica, simulando d’esserne promotore o fautore, per poter conservare il proprio potere e i privilegi della propria classe.
> - **Il termine, così come la concezione e la prassi che con esso vengono espresse, è fondato sull’affermazione paradossale che «tutto deve cambiare perché tutto resti come prima»,
> - **che è l’adattamento più diffuso**,
> - **con cui viene citato il passo che nel romanzo Il Gattopardo** (v. la voce prec.) si legge testualmente in questa forma «Se vogliamo che tutto rimanga come è, bisogna che tutto cambi» (chi pronuncia la frase non è però il principe di Salina ma suo nipote Tancredi).

Comment: Questa risposta non risponde alla mia domanda: quello che hai detto, come ho cercato di spiegare nel corpo della mia domanda, lo posso immaginare. Il problema è: perché ci sono tantissimi siti web che affermano che la frase scritta ne *Il Gattopardo* è "Bisogna cambiare tutto per non cambiare niente" quando questo non è vero? Chi ha scritto o detto questa frase per la prima volta?

Comment: Pensavo  di essere stato chiaro, sorry. Quello che voglio dire è' che la frase originale e'quella citata ( secondo me per la prima vota) nel Gattopardo. Le successive versioni, e ce ne sono varie, non sono altro che lo stesso concetto espresso con altre parole. Quando si cita questa frase, si fa riferimento al  significato più che alle parole stesse citate alla lettera.

Comment: per me Gio ha risposto ed anche bene, sono del suo stesso parere, per rendere il concetto immediato o una frase adattata a seconda, molti autori lo fanno, soprattutto critici e non di poco conto, per dare un riferimento all´originale (di solito con note) ma scritto in stile diverso a seconda della frase dove viene inserito. Inoltre, i due link sono offline Charo (potevi fare delle screen), ora come ora mi devo limitare a quello che scrivi per conto di un post che non esiste piú.

Comment: Trovo tuttavia futile, **parere personale**, questo ricercare chi o cosa ha scritto veramente, in questo banale caso intendo, se il sito riporta quella frase tra virgolette e non tra i segni corretti di citazione testuale verificare o meno é solo uno sfizio se poi non si trova nel libro la frase entro le virgolette.

Comment: Per concludere, tanto per aggiungere altra carne a fuoco, se scrivevo, come fanno alcuni critici citando a destra o sinistra o inserendo citazioni con tagli e copia-incolla coi segni corretti di citazione testuale però (e grazie a dio che esistono le note anche se non sempre): "Anche per Tommaso di Lampedusa >>Omnia mutantur, nihil interit<< nel romanzo *Il Gattopardo* per voce di Tancredi...." andavi a cercare >>Omnia mutantur, nihil interit<< nel romanzo e se veramente Tancredi diceva una cosa simile? Spero é chiaro ;)

Answer (score 0):

Credo che ci sia stata l'influenza del francese: "plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose" (più si cambia più è la stessa cosa), un epigramma di Jean-Baptiste Alphonse Karr riportato nell'edizione del gennaio 1849 della sua rivista Les Guêpes (le vespe). Il Gattopardo uscì alle stampe, postumo, solo nel 1958. 
Credo che la frase  “cambiare tutto per non cambiare niente”, scritta esattamente così, esistesse già prima del Gattopardo e che fosse appunto di derivazione quasi diretta dal francese di Karr.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie mille della risposta! Potresti aggiungere qualche fonte?

Comment: Non ho fonti, è solo una mia considerazione. Nel mondo anglosassone la forma "plus ça change.." è molto diffusa, mentre in pochi usano quella tratta dal Gattopardo. Tenendo conto che anche in Italiano la forma più usata non è esattamente quella scritta da Lampedusa, deduco che è probabile che anche la forma in uso corrente nell'Italiano provenga o sia comnque influenzata dall'originale francese du Karr.

Answer (score 0):

La frase è quella che abbiamo già detto. Il Giovane Tancredi, volendosi candidare alla prima elezione del parlamento italiano, spiega all'anziano Principe di Salina, che, se si vuole mantenere la posizione di potere e privilegio che quel titolo nobiliare gli garantiva nel vecchio Regno delle Due Sicilie, occorre ottenere una posizione simile secondo il nuovo ordinamento istituzionale portato dai Savoia. Quindi: se vogliamo che tutto rimanga com'è (cioè: se vogliamo continuare serenamente la nostra vita come finora l'abbiamo vissuta), bisogna che tutto cambi (cioè: bisogna che cambiamo la nostra vita secondo i nuovi schemi istituzionali). E questo è un pò il senso che si dà alla frase, comunque ripetuta ed anche anagrammata, nel linguaggio comune. Se si vuole mantenere una posizione, occorre adattarsi ai mutati modi di ottenerla.

Comment: Benvenuto qui, Gian Luigi! Quanto alla tua risposta, il senso di quella frase, sia nel contesto del _Gattopardo_ che applicata altrove, era ben chiaro. La domanda specifica era proprio sull'origine della riformulazione modificata rispetto all'originale.

Answer (score 0):

Credo che la frase possa derivare da una battuta dell’Ecclesiaste: ciò che è stato sarà, ciò che si è fatto si rifarà, non c’è niente di nuovo sotto il sole. La frase fu ripresa ed annotata nel registro della università di Wittenberg da Giordano Bruno in chiara polemica con le teorie di Lutero.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie del tuo intervento, @Massimo. Non credo però che la frase scritta esattamente nel modo che appare nella domanda si trovi sull'*Ecclesiaste* che, tra l'altro, che io sappia, non fu scritto in italiano ;).